# opengl texture coordinates for full-screen effect

Tags: c++, opengl, math, opengl-3, geometry-shader

how can i create the full-screen effect with a texture image ? 
till now i do this :

```
static void Draw(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture // load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture
    (
        "my_img.jpg",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
         SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);

    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

this code places my image in the top-left position of the screen, but i would like the full-screen texture effect.
So, How can i accomplish that ?

Comment: Remove the `glTranslate` transform, and set the vertex z-coords to 0.0? Make sure your projection & modelview matrices are identity.

Comment: not works :( , the screen color is black

Comment: what did you mean with identity ? sorry i'm new with opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BrettHale already suggested in the comment, just set all the matrices to the identity transformation:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Then get rid of any other transformations you have in place, like the `glTranslatef()` call you currently have in the code. Use `0.0f` instead of `1.0f` for the last coordinate of your vertices, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

ok , I did it , and now it works. for a full-screen image i added this function

```
void resize(int height, int width) {
    const float ar = (float) widthX / (float) heightY;
    glViewport(0, 20, widthX, heightY);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar+1, ar-1, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 90.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
}
```

make sure to add this :

```
glutReshapeFunc(resize); // calling the "resize function"
```